# R Fuzzy Membership function is not working correctly

Tags: r, fuzzy-logic

I have a two dimensional dataset and I want to calculate a score for the degree of membership of a new datapoint to that dataset. For this purpose I thought of using the membership function used in fuzzy c means clustering, which is as follows:

[image: membership function]
<sub>(source: [matteucc at home.deib.polimi.it](https://home.deib.polimi.it/matteucc/Clustering/tutorial_html/images/image023.gif))</sub>

I implemented this function in R and the code for it follows:

```
MembershipFunction <- function(dataPoint,class,ClassCenters,fuzzifier){
  C = nrow(ClassCenters)
  numerator = dist(rbind(dataPoint,ClassCenters[class,]))
  val=0
  for (k in 1:C){ 
    denominator = dist(rbind(dataPoint,ClassCenters[k]))
    val = val +  ( (numerator/denominator) ^ ( 2/(fuzzifier-1) ) )
  }
  answer = 1/val
  return(answer)
}
```

Now, when I give this membership function a datapoint, with fuzzifier value being equal to 2, I was hoping to get a membership function value which lies between 0 and 1. However, my values can go well beyond 100. I can't understand what am I doing wrong here. Any leads?

P.S: Although this classifies as a separate question, but if you have alternate ideas for any other membership function that I can use, please comment your ideas.

EDIT: Information on the dataset:

I am artificially generating the dataset. There are 2000 datapoints of two dimensions all of which are generated from a random normal distribution. there are four sets of 500 each, with the following means:
15,0
0,15
8,35
15,20
Variance for all the datapoints so generated is 1.

Comment: Can you also post a simple small example of the dataset you are using?

Comment: Also it seems like you have a mistake in subsetting: `ClassCenters[class,]` but `ClassCenters[k]` (no comma after *k*)

Comment: I did make a mistake in subsetting! Thank You for pointing that out. That was the mistake. It works as expected now!